# Why does the manipulation of expressions allow for L'Hôpital?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

It's been some time since I've taken a maths course and I remember to have always had this question in the back of my mind and I thought I should finally ask.

When we have expressions that are not in a form for which we can use L'Hôpital's on, we manipulate it very easily and voila, we get $\frac{0}{0}$ once we take the limit and thus we can use L'Hôpital's. Why is this the case and why don't we have to use the simplest form of an expression?

Here is an example:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
From the get go, this is not a form we can simply use L'Hôpital's on, so all we do is $x = \frac{1}{x^{-1}}$ and thus
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

I just don't understand why this makes everything work all of a sudden. Why are we not obliged to simplify this. Is it because we can derive from $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ that $x$ cannot be zero and use this rule to play around with $x$?

I would appreciate some explanation, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case and why don't we have to use the simplest form of an expression?

Because L'Hopital is concerned with a ratio of functions; it is not concerned with the ratio being in the simplest form, and nowhere mandates that. (Plus sometimes what is "simplest" is a subjective matter anyways.)

In the case of your example, we have

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}$$

as the ratio we're taking the limit of. That is, we assign $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ and $g(x)=1/x$. Then, by L'Hopital,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

if the necessary conditions hold.

Bear in mind that this fact is L'Hopital's rule (for limits $x \to \infty$ anyhow), and to your example we apply L'Hopital's rule with the definitions of $f,g$ are described earlier. The fact that $f/g$ simplifies your desired function allows us to claim the limit for your function in turn.

> Is it because we can derive from $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ that $x$ cannot be zero and use this rule to play around with $x$?

That has nothing to do with it. Since we're taking the limit as $x \to \infty$, eventually $x$ will far exceed $0$, and the singularity becomes irrelevant in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

The operation of taking limit is very "distributive" it gets distributed obver, sum, product or even is exponents: $L(f(x)+g(x))=L(f(x))+L(g(x))$.
$L(f(x)g(x))=L(f(x)) L(g(x))$, $L(f(x)^{g(x)})=L(f(x))^{L(g(x))},$ All these are allowed iff the final limit is finite.

Next, $L(\frac{f(x)g(x)h(x)}{k(x)p(x)})=L\frac{f(x)}{k(x)} L\frac{g(x)}{p(x)} L(h(x))=L\frac{h(x)}{k(x)} L\frac{g(x)}{p(x)} L(f(x)),$ Provided, these results are finite.

Similarly, reshuffling of the expression is allowed if the final limit exists (it is finite).